# Flink: Key Group 91 does not belong to the local range

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As title, the exception occurs in keyed windows,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key Group 91 does not belong to the local range.
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:139)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.getIndexForKeyGroup(HeapInternalTimerService.java:431)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.getProcessingTimeTimerSetForKeyGroup(HeapInternalTimerService.java:412)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.getProcessingTimeTimerSetForTimer(HeapInternalTimerService.java:402)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.HeapInternalTimerService.registerProcessingTimeTimer(HeapInternalTimerService.java:194)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.registerProcessingTimeTimer(WindowOperator.java:907)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.ProcessingTimeTrigger.onElement(ProcessingTimeTrigger.java:36)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.ProcessingTimeTrigger.onElement(ProcessingTimeTrigger.java:28)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator$Context.onElement(WindowOperator.java:926)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.processElement(WindowOperator.java:393)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.processInput(StreamInputProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.run(OneInputStreamTask.java:69)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

code as:

```
stream.keyBy(...).timeWindow(Time.minutes(5)).apply(...)
```

the implement of keyBy is String result. Is there any idea about it? I have seen code in `HeapInternalTimerService`, but what is the case that keyGroupId out of local range?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities that could lead to this error.

1. Your key extractor function is not deterministic, i.e., it might return different values.
2. There is a bug in Flink.

Please check that 1. is not the case. If you are sure that the key extractor is not the problem, please reach out to the Flink user mailing list or create a Jira issue.

Comment: yeah..the return value of key extractor function is deterministic, I have seen some mails same as the problem, while still can't fix the exception.

Comment: From the stacktrace I see that you are using a heap-based state backend. These store state, by simply referencing the objects (no copying or serialization happening). Are you sure, that the objects (specifically, the key attributes) are not modified after they were put into the state?

Comment: I am not sure whether it modified, this problem was fixed when I changed stream record type from case class to Tuple3, maybe cause is about deserialization of object, but not very clear inner reason.